# Textbox should not focus when click on the label in bootstrap

Tags: php, jquery

I have used jQuery validation. And using twitter bootstrap 2.3.2. Error message will display when I click the submit button. If I click the error message means the text box get focussed. How can I lost the focus ?

```
<input type="file" name="type1" id="type1">
<label for="type1">This field is required</label>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. To be able to help you we need you to show us your code!

Comment: <input type="file" name="type1" id="type1">
<label for="type1">This field is required</label>

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
$(function(){
  $('input').blur();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
<input type="file" name="type1" id="type1">
<label for="type1" onmousedown="return false;" onclick="return false;">This field is required</label>
```

The onlcick and onmousedown "return false;" will disable the default browser behavior.

Comment: Am not able to use it. Because Label is generated automatically in jQuery validation. :(